# How can I fix "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." error in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven

Here is my schema. Eclipse shows "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing-projects</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProjectForTests</name>

</project>
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that there is content AFTER the end of the root element, which means after the root element end marker.  Your screenshot is obscuring that line, so we can't tell if you have anything unusual there.